# Interpolation of iterated logarithms

Tags: logarithms, interpolation, transcendental-equations

$$\text{Let }\log^2(x)=\log(\log(x)),\\ \text{ then }f(y,x)=\log^{\lfloor1+y\rfloor}\left(\log(x)/\log((1-x^{1/x}(y-\lfloor y\rfloor))+(y-\lfloor y\rfloor))\right)$$

gives an interpolation between $\log^{\lfloor y\rfloor}(x)\text{ and }\log^{\lceil  y\rceil}(x).$

```
log[y_, x_] := N[NestList[Log,Log[x]/Log[(1-FractionalPart[y]) x^(1/x)+
FractionalPart[y] E], Floor[y + 1]][[Floor[y + 1]]]]
```

As [mike4ty4](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/11172/mike4ty4) says in his answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/238970/how-to-evaluate-fractional-tetrations),

> there isn't a unique way to interpolate the values of tetration at integer "height"

and presumably the same goes for logarithmic interpolation. Is there a generally accepted *standard method* for interpolating log functions? I looked at the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/415118/interpolation-between-iterated-logarithms), but I am not any clearer on this particular issue.